# How can I do something later, but get the applescript to return now?

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that does something similar to:

```
using terms from application "iChat"
  on logout finished
    delay 30
    … do some stuff
  end logout finished
end using terms from
```

The problem with this script, is that it also blocks the application calling it for the 30 seconds. What I would like to do then is say something like "in thirty seconds, please run this script for me", and then move all of my `… do some stuff` to that other script. But I can't see how to do that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a Mac, I assume you have Ruby installed.

What you are talking about sounds like you want a thread to sleep for 30 seconds and then execute a script in the background.

You should put `… do some stuff` in a script named dostuff.scpt and place it in your Desktop.

Then change your current script to the following code:

```
using terms from application "iChat"
 on logout finished
  do shell script "ruby -e 'Thread.new {`sleep 30 && osascript ~/Desktop/dostuff.scpt`}' &> /dev/null"
 end logout finished
end using terms from
```

A code breakdown:
do shell script (executes something from the command line)

ruby -e (executes ruby code from the command line)

Thread.new (makes a new thread to hide in the background)

` (Everything in the backtick is a shell command in ruby)

osascript (Executes an applescript from the command line)

~/Desktop/dostuff.scpt (Points the pathname to your file, the tilde substitutes to your home directory, and I assume you put dostuff.scpt on the Desktop)

&> /dev/null ([Tells Applescript to not look for output and immediately go to the next code line](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html))

I tried doing this without Ruby, however, I had no luck.  Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: The `ruby` bit isn't necessary; just call `osascript` directly and put the `delay 30` command at the top of your `dostuff.scpt` file. However, you do need to put another `&` at the end of your shell script in order to detach the `osascript` process, like this: `do shell script "osascript ~/dostuff.scpt &> /dev/null &"`